# ASP.NET Depending on data number of pages

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Right now my website(ASP.NET) has a database where it pulls data from, and the more data enter the longer the page. I am wondering how I can make it so for example once it pulls ten items from database it starts a new page and puts ten more items on the next. Basically like how http://fmylife.com does it.

Thanks

Comment: This is called LazyLoading, Check out this link; http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/load-content-while-scrolling-with-jquery/

Comment: If you are using the Gridview, Why don't you set the option AllowPaging="true" and then customize it using PagerTemplate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look att the [DataPager Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datapager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

To create a solution that works in the long run, you need to let the paging selection end up in your sql where clause, so that you only retreive the amount of records that you have specified in the PageSize property of the DataPager Control each time you round trip to the database. Otherwise it will lose it's performace when the records in the database increases.